# How do we know Schwinger functions exist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta-distributions

Let $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the dual of $C^\infty_C(\mathbb{R}^n)$, that is distributions on the set of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support. If $d\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then the $n$-point Schwinger function $S_n$ is the density of the $n$th moment of this measure, i.e. formally we can write
$$\int \phi(f_1)\ldots\phi(f_n)d\mu(\phi) = \int S_n f_1 \ldots f_n dx$$
where $dx$ is formally the Lebesgue measure.

However the above is only formal since $dx$ does not actually exist (there is no infinite dimensional Lebesgue measure that is countably additive). Thus how do we know that there exists a distribution $S_n$ such that $S_n(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ corresponds to the $n$th moment of $d\mu$?

Comment: yes, it is indeed hard to define the path integral in a mathematically rigorous way, what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the assumption is that we have a Borel measure $\mu$, what is needed is that this measure has finite moments of all orders. One can work on $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as in the question, but that's not recommended. Suppose the measure is realized on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra coming from the strong dual topology.
Then the only hypothesis should be:

$$
\forall f\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d), \forall p\in[1,\infty),\ (\phi\mapsto \phi(f))\in L^p(\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d), d\mu) .
$$

The OS axioms invoked in the other answer have no bearing on the question.

Then using the $n$-linear generalization of the Holder inequality, we have
that the map
$$
\phi\longmapsto \phi(f_1)\cdots \phi(f_n)
$$
is in $L^1(\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d), d\mu) $, for any fixed Schwartz functions $f_1,\ldots,f_n$.
As a result, the map
$$
(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\longmapsto S_n(f_1,\ldots,f_n)=\int_{\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)} \phi(f_1)\cdots \phi(f_n)\ d\mu(\phi)
$$
is well defined, and is clearly $n$-linear.

Now comes the first subtle point: this multilinear map is automatically (jointly) continuous.

As far as I know this was first proved by Xavier Fernique in the reference I mentioned in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149001/measure-theory-in-nuclear-spaces

I don't think one can find this fact in Glimm-Jaffe, nor Gel'fand-Vilenkin.

Then the second subtle point is that one needs to use the Schwartz Kernel Theorem which says that this continuous multilinear form corresponds to a continuous linear form on the bigger Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n\times d})$.
Namely, there is a unique distribution $T_n\in\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n\times d})$
such that
$$
T_n(f_1\otimes\cdots\otimes f_n)=S_n(f_1,\ldots,f_n)
$$
for all $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ in $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Finally, if one wants to go further, one can study the singular support of $T_n$ and see if it is contained in the big diagonal. Here, the OS axioms become relevant since they imply that on the complement of this diagonal, i.e, at non-coinciding points the correlations are not only infinitely differentiable but even real analytic.

Note that I explained this already in my review article ["Towards Three-Dimensional Conformal Probability"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S2070046618040015).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! If I may ask two follow up questions: 1. What is meant by the singular support of a distribution? I have seen this term come up now and again but I have not been able to find a definition.

Comment: 2. How can one obtain the Wightman functions? I assume the justification for them is similar to what you gave for the Schwinger functions. I often see it said that Wightman functions are obtained from analytically continuing the Schwinger functions and then taking the $t \rightarrow i$ limit but these are distributions so how can we analytically continue them? If this is too off-topic I can open another question.

Comment: For the quite standard notion of singular support of a distribution see page 4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1778 , for the analytic continuation from Euclidean to Minkowski, that's the whole theory behind the Osterwalder Schrader reconstruction theorem. See Section 9 of the article by Kravchuk, Qiao and Rychkov for an introduction https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP08(2021)094

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I am revisiting this question and noticed that Glimm & Jaffe prove that the analyticity axiom of OS is enough to guarantee existence of Schwinger functions of all orders. In their proof they use the Cauchy integral formula as follows: $$S_n(f_1, \ldots, f_n) = \oint S\{g\}\prod_{j=1}^n \Big(\frac{-dz_j}{2\pi z_j^2}\Big)$$ where $g = \sum_{j=1}^n z_jf_j$. But I don't understand how Cauchy's integral is being used here if $S_n$ is a distribution. I could not find a Cauchy integral formula for distributions in any reference.

Comment: There is no need for a special variant of Cauchy's formula for distributions. This is just the ordinary Cauchy formula from complex analysis, iterated because there multiple partial derivatives with respect to several variables $z_j$. The goal is to a extract a number $S_n(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$, not a distribution, because the functions $f$ are fixed when applying the Cauchy formula.

Comment: Oh yes I see now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing two issues here. dx is not a formal infinite dimensional Lebesgue measure. It is just an n-dimensional lebesgue measure representing the formal operation of integration against a tempered distribution, which is all that $\int S_n(x_1, \dots, x_n)f_1(x_1)\dots f_n(x_n)dx$ represents.

That leaves what I think is the main question, which is why $\langle\phi(f_1)\dots\phi(f_n)\rangle$ is a distribution at all. The answer comes from the regularity properties imposed on the mesaure $\mu$ by the Osterwalder Schrader axioms. Imposed as a statement on the generating functional $S(f)$, the relevant axiom is analyticity, which forces $\mu$ to decay faster than an exponential. Then a trick using the Cauchy integral formula allows you to deduce continuity on the Schwartz space. The details can be found in Glimm and Jaffe's book in chapter 6.

Comment: Thank you! I have actually been reading that chapter of Glimm & Jaffe and that's what inspired this post. In fact I posted a question on math SE regarding the measure decaying faster than an exponential (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4863760/).

Comment: If I may ask a follow up question, how does one obtain the Wightman $n$-point function $\mathcal{W}_n$? Does an expression such as $$\int S_n(x_1, \dots, x_n)f_1(x_1)\dots f_n(x_n)dx$$ exist for $\mathcal{W}_n$?

Comment: In chapter 6 they mention that $\mathcal{W}_n$ can be obtained from the the Schwinger functions by analytic continuation $t \mapsto it$ and give the expression $\langle \Omega, \phi_M(it_1, x_1)\ldots\phi_M(it_n, x_n)\Omega\rangle$, is this shorthand for replacing $t$ by $it$ in the test functions so we really have $\langle \Omega, \phi_M((f(it_1, x_1))\ldots\phi_M(f(it_n, x_n))\Omega\rangle$?